# Ext groups of affine scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. $\textbf{Spec}(A)$ is the the
spectrum of $A$. $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules. $\tilde{M}$ and
$\tilde{N}$ are sheaves associated on $\textbf{Spec}(A)$
respectively.

I want to know whether the following isomorphisms hold. Or is there
a counterexample?

$\textbf{Ext}^{n}_{\textbf{Spec}(A)}(\tilde{M},\tilde{N})\cong\textbf{Ext}^{n}_{A}(M,N)$.
$\mathscr{E}xt^{n}_{\textbf{Spec}(A)}(\tilde{M},\tilde{N})\cong\textbf{Ext}^{n}_{A}(M,N)^{\tilde{}}$.

When $\textbf{Spec}(A)$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated,
the above isomorphisms hold. (See Hartshorn's book
${Algebraic~Geometry}$, page 238)

Are there other conditions that guarantee the isomorphism?

Comment: I think the first isom is always true : Ext^n are spaces of extensions and an extension of quasi-coherent sheaves is quasi-coherent. I guess the second iso is not always true even for n=0 if M is not assumed to be of finite presentation because in this case Hom does not always commute with localization, but I don't have an easy counterexample now...

Comment: If $M$ is not finitely generated, then $\mathscr{H}om_{\textbf{Spec}(A)}(\tilde{M},\tilde{N})$ need not be quasi-coherent, even for $A$ Noetherian, so the second isomorphism can't hold in general even for $n=0$, as @user40227 says. For a simple example, take $A$ to be a discrete valuation ring, $M$ a free $A$-module of infinite rank, and $N=A$.

Comment: To emphasise, $\mathrm{Ext}$ depends only on the category, and the category of quasicoherent sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is equivalent to the category of $A$-modules.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: but when talking about the $\Ext$ group of quasi-coherent sheaves, one usually means $\Ext$ in the category of sheaves of abelian groups, and an argument is needed to show that these coincide.